# PHP Session not working after redirect using PHP

Tags: php, session, undefined, session-variables

I have 2 php pages, one for login form and 2nd the content.
When the user clicked the submit button and the page will redirect to another page, the value of session is missing and displayed `Undefined index` error in the 2nd page.

Login.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!($_POST['name'] == '' && $_POST['birth'] == '')){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $birth= $_POST['birth_Y'].'-'.$_POST['birth_M'].'-'.$_POST['birth_D'];
        $_SESSION["birth"]=$birth;
        $_SESSION["name"]=$name;
    }
}

$var = (strlen($birth)>0 && strlen($_POST['name'])>0);
if($var){
    echo("<script>location.href = '/page/details/';</script>");
exit();
}
```

2nd page:
Here's the line where the error displayed (the undefined index: name and birth)

```
session_start();
$url = 'http://example.com/folder/test.php?service=123455566666&submit=Data&name='.$_SESSION["name"].'&birth='.$_SESSION["birth"].'';
```

Comment: it'll not work because you put ! in if condition, it'll not go in that block and will not create session

Comment: @FaranAli, even I remove the ! in if still the session is not saving

Comment: First of all your not setting $_SESSION["name"] on first page,  then how will you get it on second page ?

Comment: @user3782114 it's defined inside $_POST submit

Comment: I didnt see it in your code, and error you are getting is related to error_reporting, open your php.ini file Search for error_reporting replace value with E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED, and restart sever

Comment: on first page you are setting only two session variables $_SESSION["birth"],$_SESSION["contract"] and you are using   $_SESSION["name"] on second page

Comment: @user3782114, i just have an typo error, the contract is now name but still same issue

Comment: try error_reporting solution mention above and check, it will definitely work

Comment: it's already display the error. and the error i got is undefined index for 2nd page where i already mention in my post

Comment: Error you are getting is related to error_reporting, open your php.ini file Search for error_reporting replace value with E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED, and restart sever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118401/discussion-between-user3782114-and-user014019).

Answer (score 0):

Your code on the first page really makes no sense, try this:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['birth_Y') && !empty($_POST['birth_M']) && !empty($_POST['birth_D']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $birth = $_POST['birth_Y'].'-'.$_POST['birth_M'].'-'.$_POST['birth_D'];

        $_SESSION["contract"] = $name;
        $_SESSION["birth"] = $birth;

        header('Location: http://yoursite.com/page/details/');
    }
}
```

I changed the condition to check if the fields are not empty to make it better, and I moved the page change in a place where it makes sense, alongside using proper PHP and not a crappy JavaScript hack.

Also note that the variables `$name` and `$birth` are useless here, you could just directly put the content of those variables into your session array, but I left them in order to not confuse you.

Comment: still the session is not saving and now it's not redirecting after i tried your code

Comment: Try with the current code, I didn't even payed attention to the fields you were using... You should really go back to the basics of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the entire code.

**First page:-**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['birth_Y') && !empty($_POST['birth_M']) && !empty($_POST['birth_D'])){
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $birth= $_POST['birth_Y'].'-'.$_POST['birth_M'].'-'.$_POST['birth_D'];
      $_SESSION["birth"]=$birth;
      $_SESSION["name"]=$name;
  }
}
?>
```

**Second page:-**

```
<?php
session_start();
$url = 'http://example.com/folder/test.php?service=123455566666&submit=Data&name=' .$_SESSION["name"]. '&birth=' .$_SESSION["birth"]. '';
echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: i tried your code not working. session not yet stored

Comment: no error, but i echo the `$url` and there's no value in name and birth

Comment: please try again!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118400/discussion-between-jees-k-denny-and-user014019).

Answer (score 0):

You're prematurely terminating the script with `exit`, in which case the session is not promised to be persisted. You can do that manually by adding [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) just before your redirect:

```
session_write_close(); 
echo "<script>location.href = '/page/details/';</script>";
// Or better, for many reasons: header('Location: /page/details'); 
exit;
```

To debug your `if`s, try adding something to the session outside them:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!($_POST['name'] == '' && $_POST['birth'] == '')){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still the values of session is missing after redirecting

Answer (score 0):

**You have to try with below code. It's working fine.**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if((isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != '') && (isset($_POST['birth_Y']) && $_POST['birth_Y'] != '') && (isset($_POST['birth_M']) && $_POST['birth_M'] != '') && (isset($_POST['birth_D']) && $_POST['birth_D'] != '')){
        $_SESSION["name"]   = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION["birth"]  = $_POST['birth_Y'].'-'.$_POST['birth_M'].'-'.$_POST['birth_D'];

        $var = (strlen($_SESSION["name"])>0 && strlen($_SESSION["birth"])>0);
        if($var){
            exit("<script>location.href = '/page/details/';</script>");
        } else {
            exit("<script>alert('Something Wrong!');</script>");
        }
    } else {
        exit("<script>alert('Please fill all details.');</script>");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you have any issue then put comment here!

Comment: session value from login.php is missing in the 2nd page

Comment: Check post name is match with your form post input.

Comment: there's no error, but when i echo thr `$url` there's no value in name and birth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118408/discussion-between-jitendra-patel-and-user014019).